# How to find view controller of screen

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I have seen the following code that allows someone to get the screen orientation of a device:

```
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(viewController.interfaceOrientation)) {
    //do portrait work
} else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(viewController.interfaceOrientation)){
    //do landscape work
}
```

The problem is I am not sure what to substitute for the "viewController" placeholder code. It is worth noting that I am making a keyboard app so I am not sure if I can use the same view controllers that might work for other circumstances. What controller can I use to tell the orientation of the screen?

Comment: Are you using a NavigationController?

Comment: I am using a KeyboardViewController

Comment: You might be able to just do self.interfaceOrientation there, since a UIInputViewController extends UIViewContoller. But I'm just looking it up on my phone, might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 ways.

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    //portrait    
}

if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    //landscape    
}
```

or

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) {
    //landscape    
} else {
    //portrait
}
```